# Javascript: Unable to call getter

Tags: javascript, getter-setter

```
class Clock {
    constructor() {
        this.schedule = [];
        this.simulationTime = 0;
    }

    get isEmpty() {
      return this.schedule == false;
    }

    popFirstItem(){
      if(isEmpty){
        throw "error";
      }
    }
};
```

I wish to call the getter `isEmpty()` in the `popFirstItem()` method. However, I'm not able to do it. What is the right way of calling the`isEmpty()` in the `popFirstItem()` method?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `this.isEmpty`. The `this` will always reference the class and using that reference you can call the class methods or properties:

```js
class Clock {
    constructor() {
        this.schedule = [];
        this.simulationTime = 0;
    }

    get isEmpty() {
      console.log('Inside isEmpty()');
      return this.schedule == false;
    }

    popFirstItem(){
      if(this.isEmpty){
        throw "error";
      }
    }
};  
var clock = new Clock();
console.log(clock.popFirstItem());
```